# Computing $P(X > 3Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ have the same probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f(x) = 2x, 0 \leq x \leq 1$ be the probability density function of the independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Compute $P(X > 3Y)$.

I did this:

$$p = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x/3} 4xy \mathop{dy}\mathop{dx} = \frac{1}{18}.$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  That is correct.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>3Y) &=\int_0^1\int_0^{x/3} 4xy\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&  =1/18\end{align}$$